# get second array list without duplicates and add units from duplicates to single one

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package com.mkyong.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadFromCVS {

    static ArrayList<datas> dataList = new ArrayList<datas>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ReadFromCVS obj = new ReadFromCVS();
        obj.run();
        obj.printDataList(ReadFromCVS.dataList);

    }


    public void run() {
        String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\SalesData.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String csvSplitBy = ",";
        String line = "";

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // split on comma
                String[] datas = line.split(csvSplitBy);            

                // crate data object to store values
                datas dataObject = new datas();

                // add values from the csv file to data object
                dataObject.setProductId(Integer.parseInt(datas[0]));
                dataObject.setUnits(Integer.parseInt(datas[1]));

                // adding data object to a list
                dataList.add(dataObject);
            }
            // print values stored in a datalist
            Collections.sort(dataList);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void printDataList(List<datas> dataListToPrint) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataListToPrint.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Product ID: " + dataListToPrint.get(i).getProductId() + " Units: "
                    + dataListToPrint.get(i).getUnits());
        }
    }
}
```

```
class datas implements Comparable<datas> {
  private int productId;
  private int units;

  public int getProductId() {
    return productId;
  }

  public void setProductId(int productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
  }

  public int getUnits() {
    return units;
  }

  public void setUnits(int units) {
    this.units = units;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(datas d) {
    if (this.getProductId() > d.getProductId()) {
        return 1;
    } else if (this.getProductId() < d.getProductId()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
 }

 }
```

i want to move the objects from one array list to another one without the   duplicates but when i do i need to add the units from the duplicate product id      to single product id

here is the some of the out i get after sorting the first arraylist:

```
Product ID: 10001 Units: 5
Product ID: 10001 Units: 8
Product ID: 10001 Units: 7
Product ID: 10002 Units: 4
Product ID: 10002 Units: 10
Product ID: 10002 Units: 6
Product ID: 10003 Units: 8
Product ID: 10003 Units: 6
Product ID: 10003 Units: 3
Product ID: 10003 Units: 7
Product ID: 10003 Units: 4
Product ID: 10004 Units: 6
Product ID: 10004 Units: 9
Product ID: 10004 Units: 3
Product ID: 10004 Units: 7
```

Comment: For reference: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `List`, this might be easier with a `Map`. As you parse your input file, you could store your products in a `HashMap<Integer,datas>` by `productId`. As you process new instances of `datas` from your input, check the map to see if you already have that `productId`, and if so, just update the `units` of that instance.

```
Map<Integer,datas> products = new HashMap<>();
...
// Parse your input file. For each record:
int productId = Integer.parseInt(record[0]);
int units = Integer.parseInt(record[1]);

if (products.containsKey(productId)) {
    datas existingRecord = products.get(productId);
    existingRecord.setUnits(existingRecord.getUnits() + units);
} else {
    datas d = new datas();
    d.setProductId(productId);
    d.setUnits(units);
    products.put(productId, d);
}
```

By the way, `datas` as a class name does not follow Java conventions. Capitalize the first letter, and try to name it something more meaningful. Maybe `Product`?

Answer (score 0):

why not create `Map` ?   in the for loop:

```
map.put(Integer.parseInt(datas[0]), map.getOrDefault(Integer.parseInt(datas[0]), Integer.parseInt(datas[1])) + 1);
```

and then after for loop

```
map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(o -> new datas(o.getKey(), o.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```